# jquery ui auto complete not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ui auto complete with ajax and this is the json response i am getting using firebug

```
[{"value":" test","url":"\/social\/profile\/46","label":" test"},
{"value":" test","url":"\/social\/profile\/47","label":" test"},
{"value":"test tset","url":"\/social\/profile\/62","label":"test tset"},
{"value":"test test","url":"\/social\/profile\/126","label":"test test"}]
```

This is the code

```
// Using jQuery UI's autocomplete widget:
    $('#term').autocomplete({
        minLength    : 4,
        source        : rootPath+'/search',
        select: function(event, ui) 
        {
            window.location =  ui.item.url;
        }
    });
```

I am dot getting the auto-complete list

Comment: [please find demo here](http://blogexplorerx.herobo.com/testing/demo.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a conflict with jquery validate 1.7 so moved to 1.8 of validate

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work

```
<script>
$(function ()
{       
    $("#text").autocomplete({
            source: "something.php",
            type:"json",
            select: function(event, ui) 
            {
                window.location =  ui.item.url;
            }
        });
})
</script>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>
```

For response

```
[{"value":" test","url":"/social/profile/46","label":" test"},
{"value":" test","url":"/social/profile/47","label":" test"},
{"value":"test tset","url":"/social/profile/62","label":"test tset"},
{"value":"test test","url":"/social/profile/126","label":"test test"}]
```

I guess the the response should be `"/social/profile/126"` rather than `\/social\/profile\/126"`.